# Laravel - Authorization Works from Controller Method only

Tags: php, laravel, authorization, policy

I have setup my model policy and it seems to be working when I authorize actions from within controller actions.

```
// create action
public function create()
{
    $this->authorize('create', BusinessProfile::class);
    return view('business-profile.create');
}
```

The policy for create simply returns true or false and switching the Boolean seems to be working as I am authorized based on it.

This conforms that my policies are set up correctly.

However, instead of using the `authorize` method everywhere in my controller, I tried to set up the middleware in my constructor.

The Laravel documentation shows this example.

```
Route::post('/post', function () {
    // The current user may create posts...
})->middleware('can:create,App\Post');
```

So, I wrote this in my controller constructor.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
    $this->middleware('can:create,BusinessProfile')->only('create');
}
```

However, when doing this, the action is always unauthorized.

**Bonus Information**

I went ahead and wrote garbage code in my policy to raise a syntax error and still, I get an unauthorized response which tells me my policy is not firing at all. It could be that I have not registered my policy correctly but as mentioned above, `$this->authorize(...)` works as expected.

Comment: Have you tried changing `$this->middleware('can:create,BusinessProfile')->only('create');` to $this->middleware('can:create,App\BusinessProfile')->only('create');`. Means use BusinessProfile's full class name with namespace.

Comment: If you can post policy's code, it might be helpful.

Comment: @MIdrees It seems you are right. What I was actually doing was aliasing `App\BusinessProfile` to `BusinessProfile` and then using `$this->middleware('can:create,BusinessProfile')->only('creat‌​e');` which I think does not work in Laravel. The middleware parameter has to be the fully qualified model name. For actions that have a model already created, it has to be the name of the parameter in the url. Perhaps, you can post this answer so that I may mark it? Please do be thorough though.

Comment: Thanks for your understanding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there you used alias for your model while it requires model name. At documentation states:

> some actions like create may not require a model instance. In these
>   situations, you may pass a class name to the middleware. The class
>   name will be used to determine which policy to use when authorizing
>   the action:

You can find more information here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization#policy-methods

So in the controller constructor this line:

```
$this->middleware('can:create,BusinessProfile')->only('creat‌​e');
```

will become:

```
$this->middleware('can:create,App\BusinessProfile')->only('c‌​reate');
```